# Meaning of the phrase in bold

Tags: meaning-in-context, interpretation

At this Sōsuke got to his feet. He traversed the sitting room, stepping
gingerly over Oyone’s sewing basket and scattered threads, and opened the
sliding panels to the parlor. **Its southern exposure was blocked by the
vestibule, with the result that the shoji at the other end of the room
presented a distinctly chilly appearance to the gaze of someone just coming
in out of the sunlight**. He opened these as well. Yet even here on the eastern
veranda, where one might expect the sun’s rays to strike in the morning, at
least, they scarcely penetrated at all because of a cliff-like embankment that
loomed over this side of the house,

First of all, Does "Its southern exposure was blocked by the
vestibule" mean "The vestibule blocked light from south"? and the whole phrase mean: "blocking the light from south by vestibule and being shoji at the other would cause the parlor seem very cold to the gaze of someone just coming in out of the sunlight"?

**Source**: *The Gate* by *NATSUME SŌSEKI* Translated by *WILLIAM F. SIBLEY*

Comment: The south end of the parlor (UK, parlour) was shielded from the sun by the vestibule, so that the shoji at the other end of the room looked cold to anyone coming in out of the sunny exterior. A shoji is a door, window or room divider used in traditional Japanese architecture, consisting of translucent (or transparent) sheets on a lattice frame.

Comment: So the shogi looked cold not the parlor. Am I right?

Comment: "the shoji at the other end of the room presented a distinctly chilly appearance". The Shoji looked cold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some important points:

- I imagine that there's no question that the house is not electrically lit. The novel was written in 1910, when it would not be a given even in Western settings. The architecture, then, would try to make as much use of natural light as possible. The translucent *shoji* are designed to let some light through, or can be opened for more.
- "[Southern exposure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southern_exposure_(terminology))," in the northern hemisphere, is the side that gets the most sun. Although the sun travels east to west, its position in the sky is south of center in the northern hemisphere (more, or less, depending on the season). So one might hope for natural light indoors from this side, but the parlor seems to be an interior room; it gets no southerly light because of the vestibule.
- It's a little ambiguous, but my assumption is that "the shoji at the other end of the room" are opposite where he entered, not opposite the southern side, since they open onto an "eastern veranda."

So my paraphrase of the passage is "The sliding doors facing him had a distinctly chilly appearance, since there was little natural light entering the room, and especially since his eyes had not yet acclimated from outdoors."

Comment: I meant "The light of sun" was blocked by vestibule. This phrase was a little confusing to me and I did not expect negative point